# How set the value of an input element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

This script counts the days between two dates and shows the result on a `span` element:

```
<span id="result"></span>
```

But instead I want to show the result as value of an input element:

```
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="i want count days here " />
```

How can I do this?

This is the complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
        <style>
            .ui-datepicker {font-size:11px;}
        </style>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $( "#from" ).datepicker({
                    onSelect: calculate
                });
            });
            $(function() {
                $( "#to" ).datepicker({
                    onSelect: calculate
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="formwhite">
            <table>
                <tr><td>From:</td><td><input type="text" id="from" onKeyUp="calculate();" />&nbsp;</td></tr>
                <tr><td>To:</td><td><input type="text" id="to" onKeyUp="calculate();" /></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <span id="result"></span>
        <script>
            var calculate = function() {
                var from = document.getElementById("from").value;
                var fromdate = from.slice(3, 5);
                fromdate = parseInt(fromdate);
                var frommonth = from.slice(0, 2); 
                frommonth = parseInt(frommonth);
                var fromyear = from.slice(6, 10); 
                fromyear = parseInt(fromyear);
                var to = document.getElementById("to").value;
                var todate = to.slice(3, 5); 
                todate = parseInt(todate);
                var tomonth = to.slice(0, 2); 
                tomonth = parseInt(tomonth);
                var toyear = to.slice(6, 10); 
                toyear = parseInt(toyear);
                var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;
                var firstDate = new Date(fromyear,frommonth,fromdate);
                var secondDate = new Date(toyear,tomonth,todate);

                var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay)));
                if (diffDays)
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=diffDays;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is not dublicate post

Comment: @msalman if it isn't then it could be closed on the grounds of being too specific, the point is, the answer is out there if you bothered to look for it.

Comment: Incidentally, you don't seem to use jquery or jquery-ui in any of this, so I'm going to remove those tags.

Comment: @Scott: `$(function() { $( "#from" ).datepicker({ ...` looks like jQuery.

Comment: I don't want to be *that* guy, but googling for [`jquery set input value`](https://www.google.com/#q=jquery+set+input+value) brings up the jQuery documentation as first hit: http://api.jquery.com/val/. I mean really, this is the *least* effort you can put into solving the problem yourself. Once you know that, adjusting the code is trivial, because you just have to change the part where you set the  content of the `span`. You know where that is because you wrote the yourself, right?

Comment: @FelixKling Agreed and thanks.  I was so focused on the script in the body that I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're asking the question: "How do I get a value from one field and set it in another?"  You want http://api.jquery.com/val/ :

```
$("#name").val($("#result").val());
```

`$("#result").val()` gets whatever value the element with id `result` has.

`$("#name").val(value)` sets the value of the element with id `name`

Or, simply add (or replace) the line

```
document.getElementById("name").value = diffDays;
```

in the same `if` block as where you have

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = diffDays;
```

Here's your entire `<script>` block, with my one line added:

```
    <script>
        var calculate = function() {
            var from = document.getElementById("from").value;
            var fromdate = from.slice(3, 5);
            fromdate = parseInt(fromdate);
            var frommonth = from.slice(0, 2); 
            frommonth = parseInt(frommonth);
            var fromyear = from.slice(6, 10); 
            fromyear = parseInt(fromyear);
            var to = document.getElementById("to").value;
            var todate = to.slice(3, 5); 
            todate = parseInt(todate);
            var tomonth = to.slice(0, 2); 
            tomonth = parseInt(tomonth);
            var toyear = to.slice(6, 10); 
            toyear = parseInt(toyear);
            var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;
            var firstDate = new Date(fromyear,frommonth,fromdate);
            var secondDate = new Date(toyear,tomonth,todate);

            var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay)));
            if (diffDays) /* THE NEW STUFF IS RIGHT HERE*/ {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=diffDays;
                document.getElementById("name").value=diffDays;
            } // THE NEW STUFF ENDS HERE
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: where can i put this code in to my code?

Comment: @msalman You set the result 5 lines from the bottom.  You can also set the name there (or if you don't want the answer in `result`, replace `result` with `name`.  Just make sure to add `{` `}` around that `if` block.

Comment: can u edit in to my code please

Comment: @msalman I copied all of your `<script>` code into my answer and added the one line.  Look for my comments about NEW STUFF.  If you don't want the answer to be in `result` anymore, just delete that line.

Comment: ok i replace your code in to my code and after that what i put in <input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="i want count days here " this line is correct or can i change something to here

Comment: @msalman Try it and find out.  :-)  As soon as you execute your code, it should replace "i want count days here" with the count of days.

Comment: i paste ur code in my page and change this<input name="name" type="text" id="name" value=""> but it is not working

Comment: @msalman Make a fiddle at jsfiddle.net and edit your question with the new information.

Comment: You cannot set the value of an input element with `innerHTML`. It should be `document.getElementById("name").value = diffDays;`. I assume that's a copy&paste error ;)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kuZx7/1/ see the link dear its not working

Comment: @FelixKling Wow, I messed up both on my question edit and my answer.  Thank you for catching both.

Comment: thanks felix kling now its working fine

Comment: @FelixKling If you want to write up an answer, I'll be happy to delete mine.  I was lazy and sloppy.

Comment: thanks you all  Scott Mermelstein and felixking

Comment: no problem @ScottMermelstein both are help full to me

Comment: Na, it's fine. Just did some minor fixes ;) Happy coding!

Comment: @FelixKling Well, you don't need the points - but I'd rather earn mine properly.  So I made it a community wiki.  I'd still rather not have the reputation it already got me.  You can copy-paste the answer verbatim, and I'd remove mine.

Comment: Oh come on. Everyone makes mistakes. Answers can be edited for a reason. You still earned the points because you took the time to answer and helped the OP. Don't worry :)

Comment: I'll be quiet, then, and thanks.